# How to put \dots in front equation numbers in amsmath

Tags: formatting, equations, amsmath

By default the style is

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
```

for example

```
            x+y =4         (2.1)
```

How to put `\dots` in front equation numbering such as

```
            x+y =4      ...(2.1)
```

while in the text reference remain (2.1).

and how to make it for the array by using \begin{eqnarray} \end{eqnarray}

```
      x = y+ 4         
         -Z+ E         
        + 4gh     ...(2.1)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 9):

The »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« package provides the macros `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` which allow to do this quite comfortable.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«
\newtagform{dots}{\ldots(}{)}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    (a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 \label{eqn:binomi-one}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    (a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2 \label{eqn:binomi-two}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    \usetagform{dots}
    (a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2 \label{eqn:binomi-three}
  \end{equation}
%
  The Binomi equations~\eqref{eqn:binomi-one},~\eqref{eqn:binomi-two} and~\eqref{eqn:binomi-three}.
\end{document}
```

Works of course also with the numbering scheme for equations in `report` and `book`.

---

[image]

Comment: How about the \begin{eqnarray} \usetagform{dots} \end{eqnarray} , I try to use it but cant get it

Comment: @YIT HOE NG You shouldn't use `eqnarray` in your documents. You should use the environments provided by amsmath instead.

Comment: @YITHOENG: [Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html) I'm not aware of a solution that works inside the environments of »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)«.

Answer (score 5):

You can update the `\maketag@@@` macro of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to insert the `\dots`. Here's a convenience macro that you can add to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\adddotsbeforeeqnnum}{\def\maketag@@@##1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\dots##1}}}
\makeatother
```

It acts as a switch to enable "dotted equation numbering".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\renewcommand{\theequation}{2.\arabic{equation}}% Just for this example
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\adddotsbeforeeqnnum}{\def\maketag@@@##1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\dots##1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:one}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \tag{xyz}\label{eqn:two}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \adddotsbeforeeqnnum
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:three}
\end{equation}
See~\eqref{eqn:one},~\eqref{eqn:two} and~\eqref{eqn:three}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about using the             \begin{eqnarray} 
A=
\left[\colvec{
A_{11}&A_{12}&\cdots &A_{1n}\A_{21}&A_{22}&\cdots &A_{2n}\\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \A_{n1}&A_{n2}&\cdots &A_{nn}\}\right],
\label{Equat2.4}
\end{eqnarray}